# GRUB+Windows: Как восстановить возможность выбора при загрузке?

Tags: linux, windows, grub, dual-boot

Люди добрые подсобите!

Суть такова, винт разделен на две части: в одной стоит Windows, во второй - CentOS, точнее стояло до сегодня. Сегодня пришлось вынужденно переустановить Windows и естественно пропал выбор ОС при загрузке, т.к винда затерла центос и по дефолту автоматом загружается винда. Вопрос: как восстановить возможность выбора при  загрузке.

Заранее благодарен.

P.S стояла XP, сейчас установлена семерка. Где и что надо править?

Answer (score 2):

Универсальная схема восстановления примерно следующая:

1. Загружаемся с livecd той-же архитектуры
2. Вручную монтируем root в какую-либо директорию, например в /mnt

   ```
   # mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```
3. Если /boot на отдельном разделе, то монтируем его тоже в /mnt/boot

   ```
   # mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot
   ```
4. Биндим файловые системы /dev и /proc в соответствующую директорию в /mnt

   ```
   # mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc# mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev
   ```
5. Делаем chroot

   ```
   # chroot /mnt /bin/bash
   ```
6. Теперь можно восстанавливать grub

   ```
   # grub-install /dev/sdaInstallation finished. No error reported.
   ```

Если windows не было в списке, то перед тем как делать grub-install нужно добавить в /boot/grub/menu.lst соответствующую запись.

```
title Windows 7 rootnoverify (hd0,3)makeactivechainloader +1
```

Comment: Что-то не получается, пробовал и центос-лайв, и с федора-лайв, даже с дебиен/убунту--- одна и та же ошибка; дословно не передам,но смысл -не пускают меня до редактирования / установки груба.  Также, при # mount /boot - /proc - / dev ; /mnt /bin/bash  выскакивает сообщение,что директория не существует, получается,что эти папки нужно создавать дополнительно в /mnt , а уже затем монтировать в них? А так все монтируется но не устанавливается. В чем причина?  Может это из-за того,что система в LVM ?

Answer (score 1):

Может и не очень кошерный вариант, но попробуйте Acronis OS Selector - тоже загрузчик ОС, как и Grub. Устанавливается из-под windows, ищет на всех разделах установленные ОС.

Answer (score 1):

Если видна затерла папку с grub то нужно отделить примерно 200 мб и например с live usb установить grub затем этот раздел нужно сделать загрузочным в файл menu указать откуда грузится винда.

grub setup команда вродеб. вот кстате более мене приятное руководство на инглише правда http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/grub/html_chapter/grub_3.html

Comment: короч если линух живой с директорией grub достаточно поставить метку boot на тот раздел где груб.

Answer (score 1):

apt-get install grub

Comment: В Windows 7 это очень актуально :)

Comment: ооо! в 7ке apt есть?

Answer (score 1):

Хм, может немного не по теме, но я решил для себя в пользу виндового загрузчика плюс GRUB4DOS и забыл о всех проблемах. В MBR у меня стоит виндовый загрузчик, который и грузит груб, а тот в свою очередь ArchLinux. Всё легко, просто и голова не болит при переустановке винды.

Answer (score 1):

Кстати да, если на компе с другими ОС есть винда, которую, в будущем, планируется хоть раз переустановить, то имеет смысл сразу пользоваться не GRUB'ом, а виндовым загрузчиком.

Answer (score -1):

```
/sbin/grub-install <location>
```

где <location> - куда устанавливать загрузчик GRUB Stage 1 boo. Например, что бы установить GRUB на MBR устройства master IDE на первом IDE контроллере команда будет выглядеть:

```
/sbin/grub-install /dev/hda
```

Центос сама найдет винду и сгенерит загрузочное. меню. Если криво определит найдите и отредактируйте потом в каталоге /boot конфиг меню

Comment: А в Цент как попасть через LiveCD или как? и затем,что надо делать - находясь в Live режиме; если можно чуть по-подробнее,пожалуйста

Comment: Может быть что-то изменилось за последнее время, но раньше с LiveCD было невозможно устанавливать программы.