# Grub не находит Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, grub, dual-boot, kali-linux

Родная система ноута - Windows 10 с жестким диском на 1Тб. который разделён на диск С: с виндой, и диск D: для остального. Недавно решил поставить Kali Linux второй системой: создал 2 новых раздела под корневую систему линукса и под файл подкачки. В процессе установки вылезло предупреждение что GRUB не нашел других ОС, но установку я продолжил в надежде исправить это потом.

После запуска Kali, первым делом я сделал

> apt update

и

> apt upgrade

После этого принялся исправлять неполадку.
Для сведения:

```
root@Kali:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ04ABF1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6D9FC58D-60D0-4A59-B7B0-F75910AEF24D

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1023999    1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     1024000    1228799     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1228800    1261567      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     1261568  203007354  201745787  96,2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   203008000  204799999    1792000   875M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6   204800000 1890609151 1685809152 803,9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7  1890609152 1890611199       2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda8  1890611200 1937195007   46583808  22,2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  1937195008 1953523711   16328704   7,8G Linux swap

root@Kali:~# blkid /dev/sda4
/dev/sda4: UUID="90D8F0B5D8F09AA4" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="bcbb67c9-ab8c-4c92-8abd-8e642fe71245"
```

sda4 - это раздел на 100Гб. на котором у меня и стоит винда. На попытку примонтировать его я потерпел неудачу:

```
root@Kali:~# sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda4
mount: /dev/sda4: can't find in /etc/fstab.
```

Тогда я принялся корректировать файл /etc/grub.d/40_custom
Если я добавлял туда:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,4)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 90D8F0B5D8F09AA4
    chainloader +1
}
```

То при запуске выдавало

> An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any drivers that don't contain an operating system. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart

А если так:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,2)'
    chainloader +1
}
```

То выдавало:

> An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any drivers that don't contain an operating system. Press any key to restart

НО! После этого оно каким-то невообразимым образом загружало родненькую десятку.
Подскажите как правильно пофиксить данную ситуацию.

P.S. в линуксе я - чайник, первый день с ней работаю, так что постарайтесь объяснить поподробнее :)

Comment: Может не стоит ставить дистрибутив для узких специалистов только потому что им пользовался герой сериала? Может надо начать с чего-то более дружелюбного?

Comment: `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda4` ну а монтируешь куда?

Comment: @donRumata вообще были мысли начать с Mint или Debian, но всё же получилась Kali с такой вот проблемой...  
В крайнем случае не побрезгую удалить и подчистить все следы линукса, и переустановить всё это на виртуальной машине

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/340050/262779

Comment: Kali создана для специалистов по кибербезопасности, это очень плохой выбор для начинающего пользователя линукс систем. Поставьте любую из семейства Debian, там все будет просто и понятно и непонятные моменты легко гуглятся. А захотите изучить Kali, то такие эксперименты только в VirtualBox, иначе (при попытке установки как в вашем случае) из-за нехватки опыта будут проблемы